# PXE boot Ubuntu. Right choise of Image

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation, pxe

My task is to establish server, allowing PXE boot (Ubuntu).
I have done it. Almost..
I established on Server (Ubuntu Server)

1. TFTP
2. DHCP

And process is going like this:

1. at first through DHCP client requests address which it uses for connection "Client-Server".
2. Then DHCP gives address of directory on Server which client has to request for booting to.

It all is perfectly working. When I connect my Client and Server through patch-cord and choose PXE-Boot on Client it is going okay till the moment when Client is requesting boot directory on Server. Then it all goes wrong. 
I am 100% sure, the problem is in Image Boot, which I downloaded from official site.

I just do not know which file I should pick up from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/).
If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: It depends on what you want your pxe boot to accomplish. Do you want to install Ubuntu server from network? Do you want to use a 'live' Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Have you added your ftp directory to the tftp config file? Mine lives at: `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`.

Comment: In my dhcp server config file I also added the pxeBoot menu. Here is what I added. My dhcp server and tftp are on different servers so your may be different. `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` `# added for pxe boot` `next-server 192.168.2.202;` `filename "pxelinux.0";`

Comment: yes, I want to run Ubuntu Live CD and I suppose it is what you mean under "live Ubuntu Desktop".
Yes, I added it all to config.

Comment: Does your boot menu come up? Have you created one?

Comment: To test everything up and including the menu, copy the `/boot/memtest86+.bin` memory test utility to your tftp directory. (`cp /boot/memtest86+.bin /tftpbootDirectory/mt86plus`)Add this entry to your pxe boot menu: `label Memory Tester` and `kernel mt86plus` If all is well you should be able to network boot the memory testor.

Comment: This may help with the Ubuntu 16 boot entry [link](http://www.jointux.com/configure-pxe-server-ubuntu-16-04/).

Comment: Thank you, but it is not going to solve the problem since tftp and dhcp is running good. The problem is in .iso and I need to run Live CD, not install Ubuntu

Comment: As I said, tftp and dhcp are working okay, but when Client requests a kernel it goes to initrd.gz (alternative download on official site) and it starts to install on Client Ubuntu Server and no Ubuntu Live CD, which I need

Comment: I will upvote this question because I have not found the answer anywhere and I have not been able to make this work. See [here](http://pastebin.com/e3LDWZQj) for what I have done so far. I hope this helps somewhat.